# How to get Cursor co-ordinates on mouse click relative to viewport in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to get mouse co-ordinates on a button click. If I use `event.pageX`, it returns the mouse co-ordinates relative to document. How can I convert or get the value relative to view port?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but if you're looking to get the mouse position relative to an element:

```
$("input").focus(function(e){ 
    var relativeX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; 
    var relativeY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the scroll position (`scrollTop`/`scrollLeft`) of the document from your coords to get it relative to the view port.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the your current position relative to the document - current scroll position

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to achieve? You could just wrap the button with a div and get the x,y relative to the div itself. Perhaps I am being redundant.